# Checking if a PyObject* is void in Python 3

Tags: c, python-3.x, cpython

In C, given a Python 3 `PyObject*`, how do I check if contains a Python void?

Comment: You mean you want to check `PyObject*` is `None` type?

Comment: Are you saying C's `void` maps to `None`? For instance when mapping the return value of void returning function to Python.